# large body width without horizontal scrollbar

Tags: css

I set body width to 1920px and set background-image of the same width. The image is for header. Cause I have narrower wrapper inside my body and if I put header background to header itself the header background's width is cut by wrapper's borders. 
So I put it to body but now I have horizontal scrollbar at the bottom and the center of the page is moved to right. 
How can I get rid of that scrollbar and center the page? Here is the code:

```
body {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    background-image: url('../img/menu-background.png');
    width: 1920px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-family: 'PT Sans';
}

.wrapper {
    width: 950px;
    min-height: 1658px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header a {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    width: 365px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header>
            <a href="#">
                <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
                <span>bla-bla-bla</span>
            </a>
        </header>
```

Comment: Why do you have `width: 1920px` on the body?

Comment: It's designer's idea to have header's background endless at sides on any screen. So he took the width of most large one I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent the scrollbar by adding
`overflow-x:hidden;` to your body

Comment: Thanks! It works for me. Now the background is centered and there is no horizontal scollbar.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to specify the width on the body as 1920px.

Users with larger resolution screens will see the whole background image anyway.

I'd recommend setting your background image tag on one line like this:

```
body {
    background: #f6f6f6 url('../img/menu-background.png') no-repeat center 0;
}
```