# Remove scrollbar like overflow hidden but needs to be visible

Tags: css, scrollbar, overflow, hidden

When you smallen your browser to 1000px width then there is a horizontal scrollbar, is there any way to remove this above 1000px? Check my screendump below.

I have tried a clearfix but this didn't help and tried overflow:visible;

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: ".";    
  display: block;    
  height: 0;    
  overflow: hidden; 
}
.clearfix:after {clear: both;}
.clearfix {zoom: 1;} /* IE < 8 */
```

Any clean easy way to fix this with css?

Comment: I don't get the question, what do you mean by "remove this above 1000px" ? The scrollbar disappears automatically if the window gets wider than 1000px.

Comment: possible duplicate of [large body width without horizontal scrollbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005225/large-body-width-without-horizontal-scrollbar)

Comment: Check my screendump, my images needs to be visible, but the scroll needs to be at 1000px width, When I have a browser at 1020px wide, i get a scrollbar. It needs to be like background images. overflow:hidden would normally be ok, but the images needs to be visible. Overflow hidden removes the scroll, overflow visible doesn't :(

Comment: The problem is that the images behind need more width than 1000px. So you have to shrink all images if they should still be shown... Otherwise use overflow-x.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@media all and (min-width: 1000px) {
body {
  margin:0;
}
.wrapper {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  }
}
```

If browser is more then 1000px wide there won't be horizontal scroll.

Comment: hmm, stupid haven't thought about that, it could be a solution. Thanks for that. Still wonder if there is a other way to do this with css. It should be media max-width 1000px? So all below 1000px then the overflow hidden will be set.

Comment: you where correct, I used a other method I like better because I can use overflow hidden when having a small browser

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that you can do (which still keeps your site accesible), is set the width on which the scrollbar should appear.

You can fix that by setting a minimum width for the body.

Add this to your stylesheet:

```
body { min-width: 1200px; }
```

When the browser is resized smaller than 1200px, the scrollbar will appear.

Answer (score 1):

I have decided when my browser is smaller than 1200px, the overflow:hidden; on carousel which is 1000px wide can be used.
Vladislav Stanic pointed me to the right direction, thanks all.

```
@media all and (max-width: 1200px) {
   .carousel {
        overflow-x: hidden;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `overflow-x` property to hide the horizontal scroll bar on div that creates the horizontal scrolling.

**For Instance,**

`Overflow-x:hidden;`

**EDIT**

If you want 1000px where the scroll should not come and it still comes in 1020, the case is that you have a padding/margin applied somewhere that is taking those extra pixels. You need to remove it to get your thing working.

Comment: then the other images are not visible anymore, these images needs to be visible but don't give any scrollbar

Comment: If you want 1000px where the scroll should not come and it still comes in 1020, the case is that you have a padding/margin applied somewhere that is taking those extra pixels. You need to remove it to get your thing working. - @marcoverflow